# Query database on button click mid form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, function, button

I have to create a way to get SpellMin and SpellMax from my database and I have tried various methods without success, this is my most recent attempt.
Has anybody got any insight as to how i could get this to work, I think it causes an error at the moment which causes all proceeding script not to run.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CheckCast()
    {
        <?php

            $q10 = mysql_query("SELECT SpellMin, SpellMax FROM SpellsTable WHERE SpellName = {$_POST['mydropdown']};");
            if (!$q10) die (mysql_error());
            $minmax = mysql_fetch_array($q10);
            $_SESSION['SpellMin'] = $minmax["SpellMin"];
            $_SESSION['SpellMax'] = $minmax["SpellMax"];

        ?>

        var y = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['char']->Wisdom);?>;
        var x;
        x=Math.floor(Math.random()*99);
        a = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['SpellMin']);?>;
        b = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['SpellMax']);?>;
        var c;
        c=Math.floor(Math.random() * (parseInt(b) - parseInt(a) + 1)) + parseInt(a);

        if (x <= y)
        {
            alert("Spell Cast" + ' ' + c);

        }
        else
        {
            alert("Spell Failed");
        }
    }

</script>
```

I attempted using AJAX and came up with this

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dropdown').change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'getMinMax.php',
                data: 'ddb=' + $_POST['mydropdown'].val()
                });

        });
    });


</script>
```

calling pretty much the same MYSQL statement except:

```
$q10 = mysql_query("SELECT SpellMin, SpellMax FROM SpellsTable WHERE SpellName = {$_GET['ddb']};");
```

is this correct or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You need to use ajax for this

Comment: There's no reason to have the PHP block doing the querying inside javascript function. "I think it causes an error at the moment " .... okay, what is the error?

Comment: It doesn't show an error it just doesn't run any of the JavaScript code after the query unless I comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use jQuery alone for this, since Javascript is a client-side language, and php runs on the server. All that your PHP is doing inside your script block is echoing out at page load, not at runtime for the method.

However, you can use an intermediary, AJAX(Asynchronous Javascript And XML), which sends requests to the server, and can be used to do what you want.

You can learn more about AJAX at the [jQuery website](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)

Comment: I think his odd coding style has thrown you off. There is nothing inherently wrong with what he is attempting here, and it doesn't require jquery/ajax. PHP builds the javascript function which ships to the client and runs it.  Now, the code to make what I assume is a game around all this might require jquery/ajax...

Comment: I don't think so, as the title says  mid-form. I could be wrong though. It was kinda unclear

Comment: I attempted using AJAX and came up with this 

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
$($_POST['mydropdown']).change(function() {
        $.ajax({

type: 'GET',
url: 'getMinMax.php',
data: 'ddb=' + $_POST['mydropdown'].val();
       });
});
</script>

calling pretty much the same MYSQL statement except:

$q10 = mysql_query("SELECT SpellMin, SpellMax FROM SpellsTable WHERE SpellName = {$_GET['ddb']};");

 is this correct or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: add it in to the main post